# form a list of strings from the header of a csv file in pyspark

Tags: python, csv, pyspark

I am trying to form a list of strings from the header of a csv file in pyspark. The header in csv file is in unicode format. I wrote this code which reads the header but it doesn't form the list with individual values from the header:

```
def filter(line):

    return line

read_file = sc.textFile('file:///file1.csv').zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (line, rownum): rownum == 0).map(lambda (line, rownum): line)


data = (read_file
        .map(lambda line: line.split(","))
        .filter(lambda line: len(line) >= 1)
        .map(filter))

print data.collect()
```

The output I see looks like this:

```
[[u'header1', u'header2', u'header3', u'header4', u'header5']]
```

while I want it to be `['header1','header2','header3','header4','header5']`

How can I correct it and form the list?

Comment: Just add a `[0]` at the very end of your code. Don't worry about the `u`, it's harmless. It means it's a unicode object rather than a plain string, which is actually a good thing. If you try `for header in data.collect(): print header` you'll see just the headers :-)

Comment: @AlexHall where should I put `[0]`?

Comment: What you see is a list containing one element: a list. You can extract that one element with `[0]`, i.e. `print data.collect()[0]` or `for header in data.collect()[0]: print header` (I forgot it in the above comment).

Comment: @AlexHall Also I have to do some list matching later (finding uncommon elements between this list and another list), so wouldn't this `u` create issue at that time?

Comment: No, it's fine. Try entering this in a python shell: `u'abc' == 'abc'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough to fix your specific problem:
just use `flatMap` instead of `map`

```
data = read_file.flatMap(lambda l: l.split(","))
```

Obviously taking `[0]` of the result as in `data.collect()[0]` is also a solution.

However the way you currently doing it you are iterating over the whole file to discard all lines but the first one. I would recommend using `.take(1)` on the rdd.

```
first_line = sc.textFile('test.csv').take(1)
first_line[0].split(",")
```

This second solution is a lot faster on long files.

Also note that your filter function does not currently serve any purpose, you could just leave out `.map(filter)`.